# Is there a way to set the Keyboard Type when entering a value in a StringGrid?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4, firemonkey-fm3

I would like to create an iOS App, with a fixed StringGrid. Every cell of this thing should only accept numeric values. For this I want to set the KeyboardType to vktNumberPad...but so far have not found a point of entry for this. Does anyone here have a clue on how to do this?

OK, so following Mikes hint I started to use my own column class.

```
TNumEditCell = class(TEdit)
end;
TNumberColum = class(TStringcolumn)
private
  function CreateCellControl: TStyledControl; override;
end;
```

And here comes the baffling part:

```
function TNumberColum.CreateCellControl: TStyledControl;
begin
  result := TNumEditCell.Create(Self);
  TNumEditCell(result).KeyboardType := vktNumberPad; // <- is undeclared!! What?!
  TNumEditCell(result).OnChange := DoTextChanged;
end;
```

Our good friend the compiler does not know what `vktNumberPad` is. Not even if I point him to it with a telephone pole `FMX.Types.TVirtualKeyboardType(vktNumberPad)`. I guess I'm doing something wrong :(

Final edit: Indeed I did something wrong, as Peter pointed out. So with the code above and Peters hint everything works. Ummm...how do I finish this question?

Comment: For tedit, you can set the KeyboardType in the designer. Can't you do that with the tstringgrid?

Comment: Nope, not as simply as with the TEdit. At least I could not find the property.

Comment: A grid cell is simply a TEdit so should be no problem but you'll need a custom column class so you can set it in CreateCellControl - http://monkeystyler.com/guide/Custom-Grid-Columns

Comment: @Sherlock70, have you tried to use a normal TEdit component with vktNumberPad? For me the VirtualKeyboard is always the same regardless which would point to a bug in the IFMXVirtualKeyboardService Interface.

Comment: @PeterVonča, TEdit with vktNumberPad works fine in the same App. BUT I'm using the demo version of X4...could that be the reason why my latest efforts are fruitless?

Comment: @Sherlock70, compiler doesn't know about vktNumberPad because you aren't addressing it correctly. use : `TNumEditCell(result).KeyboardType := TVirtualKeyboardType.vktNumberPad;`

Comment: @PeterVonča: D'uh! Silly me, now everything works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler doesn't know about vktNumberPad because you aren't addressing it correctly. use : `TNumEditCell(result).KeyboardType := TVirtualKeyboardType.vktNumberPad`

Answer (score 0):

Just go to de column properties and in Column style select Currency column, or Float Column, depending on the type of column will be the kind of Keyboard showsen.